# Control+C does not work in timeout-child process in bash

Tags: bash, timeout, child-process

Here goes a simple two-level script:

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 100 ./test-inner.sh
```

test-inner.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 100000
```

And, executing

```
./test.sh
```

If I try to kill test.sh process by Control+C, it does not work.
Could you help me out of here?

Comment: use the "--foreground" option for timeout to received the TTY signals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Timeout*** program might had signal handler which could be configured by user with `--foreground` option.
As you can see at it manual page:

> ```
>    --foreground
>
>           When not running timeout directly from  a  shell  prompt,  allow
>           COMMAND  to  read from the TTY and receive TTY signals.  In this
>           mode, children of COMMAND will not be timed out.
> ```

Comment: I'm sorry to invade with OT information, but you seem to have deleted a question while I was writing an answer. Here is the gist, perhaps is can be helpful to you: The provider does not retry queries. However the default commit mode requires all changes before a query to be available to the query. This means that the provider will ttemt to flush the changes. There seems to be an issue with the already performed changes. This is the reason for the Exception.